# Rectangle follow finger on canvas in scrollview

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas, windows-phone-7.1, scrollviewer

I've build view in Windows Phone 7.1 with Canvases and ScrollViewer:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SV" Margin="0,8,0,-8" ManipulationCompleted="ScheduleBackground_ManipulationCompleted" Hold="SV_Hold">
        <Canvas x:Name="ScheduleView" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,0" Height="1560" Loaded="ScheduleView_Loaded" >
        <Canvas x:Name="ScheduleBackground" >
                <Grid x:Name="HoursLegend" />
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

It's working quite well. I can see my whole canvas.
Now I want to add some interaction, let say draw red rectangle when user hold finger in some place of canvas.

```
    // in page behind
    private TaskCreator taskCreator;

    private void SV_Hold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        taskCreator = new TaskCreator(ScheduleView, e);
    }

    private void ScheduleBackground_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (taskCreator != null)
        {
            taskCreator.Clear();
            taskCreator = null;
        }
    }
```

My class to store rectangle:

```
class TaskCreator
{
    private System.Windows.Controls.Canvas ScheduleView;
    private System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e;
    private Rectangle rec;

    public TaskCreator(System.Windows.Controls.Canvas ScheduleView, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ScheduleView = ScheduleView;
        this.e = e;

        CreateTask();
    }

    private void CreateTask()
    {
        if (rec != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot create task without clear the previous rectangle");

        rec = new Rectangle();
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        rec.Stroke = brush;
        rec.Fill = brush;

        rec.Width = this.ScheduleView.ActualWidth;
        rec.Height = 45;

        Point pos = e.GetPosition(this.ScheduleView);
        rec.Margin = new Thickness(0, pos.Y, 0, 0);

        this.ScheduleView.Children.Add(rec);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        if (rec != null && ScheduleView != null)
        {
            this.ScheduleView.Children.Remove(rec);
            rec = null;
        }
    }
    }
```

And it also works. When user hold finger on canvas rectangle is shown, after he take finger away rectangle disappear.

Now i would like to move this rectangle when user move his finger (but still holding it).
How can I do that? What event should I use?
From my point of view the biggest problem here is ScrollViewer. After draw rectangle SV is still working (what is fine), but when i'm gliding SV is moving and my rectangle is always in the same postion (relative to canvas).

**What I've already tried:**

I've added ManipulationDelta="SV_ManipulationDelta" to SV:

```
    private void SV_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        if (taskCreator != null)
            taskCreator.Move(e);
    }
```

and in class:

```
    private TranslateTransform dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
    internal void Move(System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        dragTranslation.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
        rec.RenderTransform = dragTranslation;
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another event which gets called everytime the finger moves.

```
private void ManipulationDelta(object sender,System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {}
```

From this you can update the positioning of the rectangle.

Its worth noting that this event doesn't always fire on the emulator but works perfectly on a device.

Comment: Ok, but on witch object: SV (ScrollViewer) or ScheduleView (Canvas)? I've added some code, what i've tried.